# Lambda function integration with multiple SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I want to create a lambda function trigger to consume messages from the SQS queue. The official documentation of AWS says **You can associate only one queue with one or more Lambda functions**

Can a single lambda function be a consumer for multiple queues .

An example I have a lambda function named MyFunction and 2 queues queue1 and queue2. Can the lambda **MyFunction** be a common consumer of both queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate lambda with multiple SQS. Use boto3 functions if you are making the lmabda in python.

Use function like send_message() and receive_message() to add and get messages from SQS.

boto3 SQS - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, a single Lambda function can process messages from more than one SQS queue without a problem.